# How to use CASE statement along with a Sub Query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        Users.ccMailName as [User Name], 
        (CASE WHEN UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID > 0 THEN (select Team from Teams where team_ID = UserRoleAssigns.team_id) Else "All"  END) as Team, 
        Users.User_WWID [WWID], 
        Users.Created_Date, 
        Role, 
        COUNT(Role) as HasRole
     FROM  
        UserRoles 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        UserRoleAssigns ON UserRoles.Role_ID = UserRoleAssigns.Role_ID 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        Users ON UserRoleAssigns.User_WWID = Users.User_WWID
     GROUP BY 
        Users.ccMailName, Users.Created_Date, Users.User_WWID, Role, UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID
) as Tbl1
  PIVOT (
    SUM(HasRole)
    FOR [Role] IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS pt
ORDER BY Created_Date desc '
```

When I run it I am getting the following error:

> Invalid column name 'All'.

The query works fine without the case statement with just the sub query alone. Essentially, first I want to check whether `UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID > 0`. If so, then get data from the subquery.

Otherwise default the value to "All".

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use `CASE` like that - in T-SQL, `CASE` is an **expression** that can return different values - but it is **NOT** a flow control statement that can handle code execution and code blocks

Comment: You seem to be building this as a dynamic SQL statement.  Use `if` instead.

Comment: `"All"` should be in single quotes.

Comment: When I tried single quote, it doesn't even compile. I get this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'All'.

Comment: I tried If, as follows: IF UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID > 0 
 BEGIN
  (select Team from Teams where team_ID = UserRoleAssigns.team_id)
 END 
 ELSE
  "All" as Team. But got this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Incorrect syntax near 'All'.

Comment: IF UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID > 0 
 BEGIN
  (select Team from Teams where team_ID = UserRoleAssigns.team_id)
 END 
 ELSE
  "All" as Team. But get this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Incorrect syntax near 'All'.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite your sql like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        Users.ccMailName as [User Name], 
        (CASE WHEN UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID > 0 THEN UserRoleAssigns.team_id Else 'All'  END) as Team, 
        Users.User_WWID [WWID], 
        Users.Created_Date, 
        Role, 
        COUNT(Role) as HasRole
     FROM  
        UserRoles 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        (select * from UserRoleAssigns u left join select Team from Teams t on u.team_ID=t.eam_ID) UserRoleAssigns
        ON UserRoles.Role_ID = UserRoleAssigns.Role_ID 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        Users ON UserRoleAssigns.User_WWID = Users.User_WWID

     GROUP BY 
        Users.ccMailName, Users.Created_Date, Users.User_WWID, Role, UserRoleAssigns.Team_ID
) as Tbl1
  PIVOT (
    SUM(HasRole)
    FOR [Role] IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS pt
ORDER BY Created_Date desc '
```

if you are assigning the sql to a variable,which I think you are doing because of the construct of the pivot part, then you may need to escape the single quotes in 'All' by using two single quotes i.e ''All''